# I get only column headers using sqldatareader and datagridview

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

I have a `SQL Server 2008` express with a database and a `table` and using `VB 2010` express.

I am trying to read from that table with `sqldatareader`, but I only one row in the `datagridview` with the column headers, no row with data.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm a newbe).

The connection string is :
`Data Source=xxxxxxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Masteca_Inventory;Integrated Security=True`

```
Dim searchStr As String = ""
Dim connetionString As String
Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
Dim sqlStr As String

Public bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()

connetionString = My.Settings.SQLconnSTR
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Piese WHERE " & searchStr  'searchStr is OK I fill it elsewhere
sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

Try
    sqlCnn.Open()
    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlStr, sqlCnn)

    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

    Using sqlReader

        Dim dTable As New DataTable
        dTable.Load(sqlReader)
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dTable

    End Using

    SearchReport.DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
    'SearchReport is another form

    sqlReader.Close()
    sqlCmd.Dispose()
    sqlCnn.Close()

    SearchReport.Show()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: _"searchStr is OK I fill it elsewhere"_ `searchStr` is **not** ok since you are open for sql-injection if you concenate your sql-query. Use sql-parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However I do not know what is sql-injection or sql-parameters, but I will look it up.

Comment: It looks like the sqldatareader does not execute. I've put this line after the sqlCmd.EcecuteReader()                                         Debug.WriteLine("Datareader has rows: " & sqlReader.HasRows)           and it says: False

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the data as a group (you are fetching only one result).

You will need to adjust the code to use a `While` sqlReader.Read;

Example;

```
Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

While sqlReader.Read()
    Try                      
       'Do the work needed 
       rowResult += sqlReader(0) 'This will contain the result script
    Catch ex As Exception
       'Catch exception
    End Try

End While
```

Something like that should work (I have not tested the code but the concept is the same).

**PS - I strongly suggest you adjust your script to add a `Where` clause and / or the columns needed (Select * is not a "good practice")**

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I commented above, I think have a problem with the execution of the sqldatareader.     I tried the While loop only with a Debug.Writeline, but the While loop is not executed.

Comment: @user2742655 So then if you take that same script and run it from within a SQL editor, does it return results?

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for the big fuss! I messed up the SQL string - mea culpa. The sqldatareader did not read because there was nothing to read.                                                                  From now on I will always put the sqlstring within the try block.

Comment: Thats great to hear - if you happy with it, would you please mark this as the answer. Thanks and happy coding.